# How to use OpenType fonts in a PostScript program?

Tags: macos, postscript, opentype

I am writing a PostScript program to print name badges and would like to include an OpenType font such that I can use it later on. OpenType files are binary files and I am looking for advice how such fonts are included into PostScript files as they are sent to a printer.

I am developing on Mac OS X which might be relevant if I need conversion tools. I have used successfully Type-1 fonts in my program and I am aware of font re-encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following process worked for me on Mac OS X 10.6:

1. I used [FontXChange](http://www.fontgear.net/fontxchange.html) on OS X to convert an OpenType font (`*.otf`) to a binary `*.pfb` font using the setting for Windows. (The setting for OS X would create font files where the actual PostScript code ends up somewhat unaccessible in resource forks.)
2. I converted the binary font in `*.pfb` format to ASCII PostScript format (`*.pfa`) using `/usr/bin/pfbtops`. The resulting font in ASCII PostScript format can be easily embedded into a PostScript file that is sent to a printer.